# creating new variables with ifelse statements and forloops in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I need to create a dummy variable for every single unique categorical value of a variable in my dataframe.

Im wondering if I can turn `unique(data$variable)` into a vector and then create a forloop that assigns a new variable por each value. Something like

```
for(val in vector){

data$print(val)<- ifelse(data$variable == val, 1, 0)}
```

When i try that I get this error:

> invalid function in complex assignment

Changing the code to 
`for(val in vector){

```
data$print[val]<- ifelse(data$variable == val, 1, 0)}`
```

produces the error

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, print, value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>   :    replacement has 480437 rows, data has 480436

data$variable is also as.factor already

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It would help to see (part) of your dataset. Also, are you trying to loop through data$print? If so this should be data$print[val]

Comment: simply converting that variable to factor should work I think i.e. `data$variable <- as.factor(data$variable)`

Answer (score 0):

The correct code was

```
`for(value in vector) { 
  nam <- paste(value)
  assign(nam, ifelse(data$variable == value, "1", "0"))
 data<-cbind(data, get(value))
}`
```

where assign creates objects for the result of each ifelse statement and and cbind joins them to the data frame